# parsing Json data with jq

Tags: json, jq

Need help in parsing Json data using jq , I used to parse the data using json path as [?(@.type=='router')].externalIP. I am not sure how to do the same using jq.

The result from the query should provide the .externalIp from the type=router.
198.22.66.99

### Json data snippet as below

```html
[
  {
    "externalHostName": "localhost",
    "externalIP": "198.22.66.99",
    "internalHostName": "localhost",
    "isUp": true,
    "pod": "gateway",
    "reachable": true,
    "region": "dc-1",
     "type": [
      "router"
    ],
    "uUID": "b5f986fe-982e-47ae-8260-8a3662f25fc2"
  },
  ]
```

##

Comment: I use to do this with json path query as  [?(@.type=='router')].externalIP   i am not sure how to do the same with jq .

Comment: Add this to your question. Also check how to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No need to post 100s of lines of json to demonstrate the problem..

Comment: Noted , my bad!

Comment: Just go ahead and change the question. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44409037/edit) it

Answer (score 0):

```
cat your-data.json | jq '.[]|.externalIP|select(type=="string")'
"198.22.66.99"
"192.22.66.29"
"192.22.66.89"
"192.66.22.79"
```

explanation:

```
.[]                   | .externalIP            | select(type=="string")    
for every array entry | get field 'externalIP' | drop nulls
```

---

EDIT/ADDENDUM: filter on type (expects router to be on index 0 of type array)

```
cat x | jq '.[]|select(.type[0] == "router")|.externalIP'
"198.22.66.99"
"192.22.66.89"
```

Comment: Thanks, i would like to extract  externalIP for only the array     "type": [
      "router"
    ],   . The resulting output should only contain 198.22.66.99

192.22.66.89.

Answer (score 0):

The description:

> i would like to extract externalIP for only the array "type": [ "router" ]

The corresponding jq query is:

```
.[] | select(.type==["router"]) | .externalIP
```

To base the query on whether "router" is amongst the specified types:

```
.[] | select(.type|index("router")) | .externalIP
```